# Split monomorphisms of modules - does the finite case imply the infinite case?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, modules

Let $k$ be a field, $A$ a finite dimensional $k$-algebra, $X$ a finite dimensional indecomposable (left) $A$-module and $M$ an infinite dimensional (left) $A$-module. Further $X\subseteq M$ and for every finite dimensional $A$-module $N$ with $X\subseteq N\subseteq M$ the inclusion $X\hookrightarrow N$ splits. Is it true that $X \hookrightarrow M$ must split? If not, does somebody know a counterexample?

Comment: No way, doc! You should be able to hook up X to the top layer of the Loewy structure of M. I have tried to cook something up but it did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $A$ is a finite-dimensional $k$-algebra, $M$ is the direct limit of its finite-dimensional submodules $N$ which contain $X$. Now the sequence $0\to X\to M\to M/X\to 0$ is pure-exact, since it is the direct limit of the split exact sequences $0\to X\to N\to N/X\to 0$. Also $X$ is finite-dimensional over $k$, so it is pure-injective. Thus the sequence splits, and $X$ is a direct summand of $M$.

Comment: I read up on pure exact sequences and pure injective modules, and this proof seems to be correct. Could you translate it into a more elementary proof?

Comment: @kevkev1695 For essentially the same proof, but without using the word "pure" (I'll use the same notation, with $\operatorname{D}$ for vector space dual): $DX\otimes_AX\to DX\otimes_AN$ is injective for every $N$. Taking direct limits, $DX\otimes_AX\to DX\otimes_AM$ is injective. Taking duals, $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,X)\to\operatorname{Hom}_A(X,X)$ is surjective. So $X\to M$ splits.