# Split epimorphism of modules - does the finite case imply the infinite case?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, modules

Let $k$ be a field, $A$ a finite dimensional $k$-algebra, $X$ a finite dimensional indecomposable (left) $A$-module and $M$ an infinite dimensional (left) $A$-module. Suppose further we have an epimorphism  $M\twoheadrightarrow X$ such that if it factors as $M \twoheadrightarrow N \twoheadrightarrow X$ for a finite dimensional $A$-module $N$ and an epimorphism $M \twoheadrightarrow N$, then $N\twoheadrightarrow X$ splits. Is it true that $M\twoheadrightarrow X$ must split? If not, does somebody know a counterexample? In particular I'm interested in the case that $M$ is countably generated.

EDIT: What I could show (in the case that $M$ is countably generated) is that we find finite dimensional modules $X=X_0, X_1, X_2, \dots$ such that $M$ is a submodule of $\prod_{i=1}^\infty X_i$ and the composition $M \hookrightarrow \prod_{i=0}^\infty X_i \twoheadrightarrow \prod_{i=0}^j X_i$ is surjective for all $j$. Maybe someone can do more with that?

EDIT 2: The dual setting was answered here: [Split monomorphisms of modules - does the finite case imply the infinite case?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409876)

Comment: @abx I think the intended hypothesis was that, for every finite-dimensional $N$ and every factorization of $M\to X$ through epimorphisms $M\to N\to X$, the $N\to X$ part splits.

Comment: @Andreas Blass: Oh, right. I will delete my comment, which is irrelevant.